# populate object with new object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

how do I combine two objects so that it looks like the following code

```
{
  category: 'product 1',
  sub_category: 'sub product 1',
}
{
  nama: "nama product1",
  jenis: "jenis1"
}

{
  nama: "nama product1",
  jenis: "jenis1",
  category: {
    category: 'product 1',
    sub_category: 'sub product 1',
  }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: does `category` have to be nested? or did you make a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const x = {
  category: 'product 1',
  sub_category: 'sub product 1',
}
const y = {
  nama: "nama product1",
  jenis: "jenis1"
};

const z = {...y, category: x};

const log = document.querySelector(`pre`);

log.textContent = `nested:\n` + JSON.stringify(z, null, 2);

// or flattened:
const zz = { ...y, ...{ category: x.category, sub_category: x.sub_category } };
log.textContent += `\n\nflat:\n${JSON.stringify(zz, null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this, assuming that all objects have the same format

```js
const obj1 = {
    category: 'product 1',
    sub_category: 'sub product 1',
}
const obj2 = {
    nama: "nama product1",
    jenis: "jenis1"
}

obj2.category = obj1;
console.log(obj2);
```